# How use the Samsung Galaxy S3 stock contact/phone app with custom ROM?

Tags: contacts, samsung-galaxy-s-3, custom-roms

I have a Samsung Galaxy S3 with Verizon with the custom ROM Cyanogenmod 10.1. It has it's own people app and dialer.

Previously, before I rooted my phone and installed the Cyanogenmod, the S3 comes with Samsung's TouchWiz along with all of Samsung's built-in apps. One of the apps was their dialer and contacts app.

Is there anyway, while using the Cyanogenmod, to replace the Cyanogenmod's default phone app with the original S3's phone app? Is there an apk file of the phone app I could install?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get a stock ROM of the same Android version. In this case 4.2 JellyBean, since its the base of Cyanogenmod 10.1.

Once you get the stock ROM, you can open it with any zip viewer and get the apps you want from `/system/app`, then you just connect the phone via USB and `adb push` the apps to `/system/app` in the phone. Be sure to wipe cache/dalvik and reboot to apply the changes.

Another easier way is if you have a nandroid of your last stock ROM (and its JB also). You can open the nandroid with WinRAR and get the needed apps from `/system/app` without searching for the stock ROM.

Comment: Will this work - I mean even if the resources (in framework-res.apk) between CM10.1 ROM and stock ROM are out of alignment, this is going to cause trouble - not sure, just a hunch :)

Comment: Where can I find the Samsung Galaxy S3 stock ROM?

Comment: You can check if they're already uploaded to SamMobile: http://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/